# In sklearn regression, is there a command to return residuals for all records?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I know this is an elementary question, but I'm not a python programmer. I have an app that is using the sklearn kit to run regressions on a python server.

Is there a simple command which will return the predictions or the residuals for each and every data record in the sample?

Comment: You can make the prediction on the train set. Take the difference between the prediction and train set. You will have residuals.

Answer (score 25):

In sklearn to get predictions use `.predict(x)`

```
modelname.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
prediction = modelname.predict(x_test)
residual = (y_test - prediction)
```

If you are using an OLS stats model

```
OLS_model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()  # training the model
predicted_values = OLS_model.predict()  # predicted values
residual_values = OLS_model.resid # residual values
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use `fit()` to get predictions and residual is simply the difference between the actual value and predictions.